# z3c.form and Plone - add custom css file to a form without using a custom template

Tags: plone, z3c.form

In a project I'm working on we've defined a simple z3c.form, it looks like this.

```
class IImportCandidateForm(Interface):
    csv_file = NamedFile(title=_(u'CSV file'))

class ImportForm(form.Form):
    fields = field.Fields(IImportForm)
    ignoreContext = True

    def updateWidget(self):
        super(ImportForm, self).updateWidget()

    ... snip ...

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Import')
    def handleImport(self, action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()
        if errors:
            self.status = self.formErrorMessage
            return 
        file = data["csv_file"].data
```

Is there a way to associate a custom css file with this form without first wrapping it in a custom page template with the form?

Comment: So far I haven't found a solution outside of creating a custom .pt template file and adding the following code at the bottom of my .py file: report_form_frame = plone.z3cform.layout.wrap_form(ImportForm, index=FiveViewPageTemplateFile("import.pt")). I'm looking at this example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.z3cform#form-main-template-override

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Unless you use a form wrapper, the form's template renders only the form and not the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

In you are using this form in a custom view, you have a class style added to the `body` class (something like `template-yourviewname`). So you can add you CSS rules to a main CSS resource, loaded in every page, but prefix every rule with `.template-yourviewname`.